# Ways to implement touch sensitive surface?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

I'm building a tic tac toe board for my kids where tapping on a plexiglass surface in any one of the 9 squares would light it up.

What are some ways I can pull off making each of those 9 squares touch sensitive?

Doesn't need to be anything fancy, but the kicker is that it can't be something attached directly to the plexiglass surface (as that'd obscure the LED light underneath).

Current thinking is [buy a sheet of this pressure-sensitive conductive material](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1361) and cut it in to squares, then somehow transfer pressure form the plexiglass down to the square on the bottom of the box, but I may be overcomplicating it.

Comment: Can the nine squares of plexiglas be configured as floating items, perhaps secured along only one edge? If so, you could place a pressure sensor under each of the nine pieces. The illumination need not be directly under the plexiglas and can instead be mounted to provide an edge-lit panel. You would want adjacent tiles to be painted black on the edge to prevent cross-illumination. There are a number of such sensors on Adafruit, but the more practical unit is seven dollars. You may be able to use the sheet stuff and create something that works.

Comment: If you have to have under-tile lighting, you could have through-hole standoffs that pass the force under a substrate to the conductive material. I think your question is more engineering than arduino, but it should be easily resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Transparent touch sensitive surfaces are usually based on parasitic capacitance like on an iPhone.  While you can buy loose glass touch surfaces, it is difficult to use such devices if not already attached to an LCD.  The same is true for the much cheaper resistive touch surfaces like on a Newton.

If you are already using LEDs, I would suggest investigating using the LED to detect the light from the reflection of a finger.  I found people talking about this [here](http://www.thebox.myzen.co.uk/Workshop/LED_Sensing.html), [here](http://www.bitartist.org/2008/10/led-used-as-touchinput-sensor.html) and [here](http://makezine.com/projects/make-36-boards/how-to-use-leds-to-detect-light/).

I believe this is a still from a video that someone else made using this technique:

[image]

For your tic tac toe box I could see touching a location for X's or for O's.  Then touching 1 of 9 boxes you would want to place the symbol in.

Added later...

As @Gerben pointed out there are other options.  I like solving hardware problems in software.  And reversing the potential on an LED then sampling the voltage over time is a snap to implement on many modern embedded processors.

If you are open to hardware solutions, microchip.com makes a [chip](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/MGC3030) which projects an electrical field in front of a PCB for 3 dimensional gesture recognition.  However, the PCB layout is touchy.

[image]

Also, there are gesture sensors that (probably) use IR radiation to track movement.  [Here's one](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12787) that supposedly does X Y & Z as well as sense colors.  And it sounds like there is already an [Arduino library](https://github.com/sparkfun/APDS-9960_RGB_and_Gesture_Sensor/tree/V_H1.0_L1.4.1) written for some simple gestures. Looks like there's a [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/A3QRyixnEl8) as well.

Comment: I'd probably use some dedicated [IR reflective sensors](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2349), instead of using the leds you are driving. That would make things a bit easier, and probably more accurate.